# Image not uploading (input name not found)

Tags: php, image, blob

I have a image uploading code using BLOB.
I am getting this error.

```
Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\sj\ad_posted.php on line 19
```

HTML:

```
    <form action="ad_posted.php" method="post">
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td>COMPANY NAME:</td>
    <td align="justify"><input name="ad_name" type="text" size="40" maxlength="25" /></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>LOCATION:</td>    
    <td align="justify"><input name="ad_location" type="text" size="40" maxlength="25" /></td>
</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>CONTACT NO:</td>    
    <td align="justify"><input name="ad_contact" type="text" size="40" maxlength="25" /></td>
</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>IMAGE:</td>
    <td><input name="image" type="file" style="height:30px;"/></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is the PHP code which uploads the image:

```
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if(!isset($file))
{
    echo "Please select an image";
}

else 
{ 
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));   
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    if($image_size == FALSE)
    echo "Thats not image";

    else 
    {
        $sql = "Insert into advertisement (ad_name,ad_location,ad_contact,ad_category,ad_image) values  ('$name','$location','$contact',$category,'$image')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

PS: This code is working properly on my other site. I copied the same code without any changes on my new project and I am getting this error! Whereas I do see any problem, in the error which it is showing.

Comment: we see `</form>` but no `<form....` which we don't know if you are using a POST method and a valid enctype.

Comment: Is this on the same page? does the form has `action = ""` or what?

Comment: plus, you need to escape the file going into db when using BLOB, but make sure it's not too big, it has its limits. Not to mention 1x `if` and 2x `else`.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari might have action, since OP's getting PHP error he must have been redirected

Comment: blob gives me the creeps, lots of bad DB corruption memories

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah, then we got to see if he using the correct `enctype="multipart/form-data"` along with the `method`

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari "Guesswork" is fun when playing "Charade", sure.

Comment: @Fred-ii- second `if` just above `echo "Thats not image"`, ninja-hidden

Comment: @AlanMachado Probably. I'm a *"post that code, and I'll take it literally"* kind a guy ;-)

Comment: Wake me up when the _OP_ replies.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari [This too...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIgZ7gMze7A)

Comment: Ahh.... I have pasted only half html code! which was needed! according to me! Entire code updated!

Comment: Are you getting this error after pressing the submit button or when you load the page? I would suspect you are getting the error when you load it, because when you load, $_FILES['image'] is not populated, and you are trying to access tmp_name on an undefined object. Usually good way to start is by checking if the submit button was pressed (by checking the value for $_POST['submit'] (isset and if equal to Submit for your example). If you don't want to change code, then set in your php ini to : error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your edit `<form action="ad_posted.php" method="post">`

well there you go, you're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

It's required when dealing with files.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: @ThesK hehe, see? It paid off ;-) *Cheers* and you're welcome.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari That was my first *educated* guess lol hence my first comment to the OP ;-) *"we see </form> but no <form.... which we don't know if you are using a POST method and a valid enctype"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hah, its always a pleasure seeing you happy kay? ;)

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari *Likewise* ;-)